# Android activity not rotating on phones (but does on tablets)

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, admob, android-viewpager

I have an activity that does not rotate on some devices, but does rotate on others.

Specifically it rotates on tablets tested so far, but not on phones. My other activities with the same manifest parameters do rotate as expected.

This view has a viewpager as well as admob ads. Is there a known bug/feature with these layout elements that can override rotation parameters? I don't have anything saying the orientation should stick to landscape or portrait in the manifest or in the code.

If there isn't anything known, I can post code later.

Comment: are you sure isnt the autorotate option in your phone?

Comment: Yes - what Paschalis said. Also which devices? Have you attempted to replicate against an emulator?

Comment: Since you say you handle `configChanges` yourself, if you are targeting API >= 13, are you including `screenSize`?  It also changes with orientation when targeting higher APIs.  See notes on `orientation` and `screenSize` in [`configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)

Comment: @iagreen I'm not using `screenSize` although I did read about it. I am testing on android 2.3.x for phones as well as an android 4.1 nexus 4, these do not rotate on this one activity. The honeycomb 7" tablet does rotate. Thats all the info I have. on all the other activities in this app they all rotate as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that this theme

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

doesn't allow rotation on certain screen sizes

Answer (score -1):

In manisfest insert the activity parameter android:configChanges="orientation" and not insert the screenOrientation parameter.

Comment: I already have that, I already handle configChanges on my own. The activity doesn't restart when it rotates on tablet devices.

Comment: I doubt that this will be a solution. This has nothing to do with "works on some devices"...

Comment: This is neither a solution, nor an answer.  And please stop spreading the myth that android:configChanges="orientation" is a quick fix for Activity life cycle or orientation problems.